# Do SARS-CoV-2 virus particles really travel through filopodia and "emerge from the tips"?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, coronavirus, intracellular-transport, locomotion

Watching the new University of California San Francisco video [Coronavirus forces cells to produce tentacle-like structures that infect neighboring cells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjFFGCsu2lk) I saw

> The growths spread out, and coronaviruses emerge from the tips, ready to infect neighboring cells.

[image: UCSF Video The growths spread out, and coronaviruses emerge from the tips, ready to infect neighboring cells.]

The caption on the video page includes the following:

> When a cell is commandeered by SARS-CoV-2, however, these same kinases behave in ways that disrupt normal cell function and transform the host cell into a virus factory. Cell division comes to a halt, inflammation pathways are activated, and the cell even begins to produce tentacle-like structures known as filopodia, which protrude from the cell's surface and may serve as molecular highways that help the virus spread rapidly to neighboring cells.

**Question:** Do SARS-CoV-2 virus particles really travel through the induced [filopodia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filopodia) and "emerge from the tips" of at least some kinds of human cells? Are they transported along the microfibers to the ends as part of this process? If so, how is this known? Images here and elsewhere seem to shown the virus particles dotted randomly along the filopodia and other areas of the cell surface as well.

Comment: It surely depends on the cell line, is it specific to vero E6 cells and maybe some models of epithelials (Caco-2, HAE, where filopodia are desired) ? There are some images where the virions budding vesicles seem to be exocytosed normally. You can try emailing the authors of [1](https://www.globenewswire.com/fr/news-release/2020/06/28/2054406/0/en/Cell-Publication-Elucidates-How-SARS-CoV-2-Dramatically-Rewires-Important-Cell-Programming-Identifies-Existing-Therapeutics-That-May-Fight-COVID-19.html) and  [2](https://www.cell.com/cell/pdf/S0092-8674(20)30811-4.pdf).

Comment: @reuns I'm too shy